Worklogs in Tempo Timesheets (DS not Cloud) not working updating even with 200 msg
I have a LOT of tempo worklogs that I have to go through and change the billable seconds to something other than the logged time. While retrieving the records isn't a problem (with a little workaround), the solution for updating the records are proving to be elusive.
As per the documentation I am using the PUT method to  http://jira.mycompany.co.uk/rest/tempo-timesheets/3/worklogs/61727
My request payload is:
{"comment":"checking the existing code changes",  "billableSeconds":780,  "remainingEstimate":2820,  "includeNonWorkingDays":false, "attributes":{} }
I get a 200 success message when running this but the response shows that nothing got updated (note billed seconds:
Response for worklog 61727: 200, {"timeSpentSeconds":3600,"billedSeconds":3420,"d....
The documentation calls for billableSeconds but I have used billedSeconds as well thinking that there was an error in the docs.
I have tried including all fields in the payload as well as only including the fields I want to update but I get the same result.
I have tried both in postman and in Googlescript but to no avail.
Does anybody have any insights?

Tempo stores worklog data in a separate DB on their servers. It is later synced with Atlassian DB. I assume that you use Tempo API for a PUT method, but Jira API for a GET request. Use Tempo API for validation if your PUT request succeeded.
